# Passing a list from controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two models in my application: Account(containing 60 fields) and Favorite (.dbml files)
I got a list lstResult by performing some joins between those two tables. 
lstResult now contains Account data but having lesser fields(7-8).
How to pass this lstResult from controller to view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a viewModel class with new properties(fileds) that you want then fill the class with your query then pass it to view

Answer (score 0):

you have several options to achieve this, i put 2 options that you can use.
1.- 
make your view strongly typed, in you view:

```
    @model List<typeOfyourlist>
```

then you will able to access to your list

```
   @for(int index=0;index<Model.Count();index++)
    {

    }
```

in you controller:

```
    public ActionResult YourViewName()
    {
        List<typeOfyourlist> lstResults = new List<typeOfyourlist>();
       //...
       //.. populate your list..
       //
      return View(lstResults);
    }
```

2.-

in you controller:

```
    public ActionResult YourViewName()
    {
        ViewBag.LstResults = yourLstResult;

      return View();
    }
```

in your view

```
     @if(ViewBag.LstResults != null)
      {
        for(int index=0;index<ViewBag.LstResults.Count();index++)
        {

        }
       }
```